# file upload to the wrong directory

Tags: php

I try to use the copy() function in php to store two same files in the sever at one time, I have specified the directory for the copied file, but it doesn't go to the directory I specified which is "edituploads" folder, instead it goes to the current directory which the upload php scrpit is located. and I have used the copy() function three times , is that a problem?
Any one could tell me what's wrong, thanks alot.

here is my php code:

```
  if (!empty($_FILES))
  {
      $a = uniqid();
      $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
      $targetpath4=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/example/upload/edituploads/";
      $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $a.".jpg";
      $targetFile4 =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath4) . $a.".jpg"; 
      move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
      copy($targetFile, $targetFile4);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

php's copy/move commands work purely on a filename basis. You can't specify a directory as a source or a target, because they don't operate in directories. It's not like a shell where you can do

```
$ cp sourcefile /some/destination/directory/
```

and the system will happily create 'sourcefile' in that directory for you. You have to specify a filename for the target, e.g.:

```
$ cp sourcefile /some/destination/directory/sourcefile
```

Beyond that, your move command is usign`$targetPath`, which your code snippet doesn't define, so it's going to just create a `$a.jpg` filename in the current working directory.

And your copy() command is using `$targetFile4`, which is based off `targetPath3`, which is also not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the file first, then move over the TMP to the other directory.

copy($tempFile,'somePlace_1');
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, 'somePlace_2');

Comment: Not relevant, if the OP's code was working properly, the file would be getting moved to `$targetFile`, then being copied FROM `$targetFile`.

Comment: I thought he was trying to copy the file from tmp_file after he moved it..But i looked over his code again, ya it SHOULD work if he copies it from the path that he moved the tmp_file. Like yous said tho, they are missing parameters.